# GlassFish Java EE index file url change

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, java-ee-6

Good day,
i have app on **localhost:8080/test/HelloWorld.jsp**, and on  **localhost:8080** i have information about GlassFish.
How can i force localhost to open HelloWorld.jsp neither GlasFish index.html, and other page like **localhost/test/hello/HeloWorld.jsp** to open at **localhost/hello/HelloWorld.jsp**???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to set the context root in your `glassfish-web.xml` (If you don't have this file, create it in `WEB-INF`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/hello</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```